# List only bottom level directories using find

Tags: bash, find, bash-scripting

So, let's say I use find to search a directory for folders.

```
find "/home/user/Documents" -type d -print
```

While this does list all the directories in said location, I only want to get the paths of the bottom level directories. (Ex: Directories that have no subdirectories/folders)

Is there an easy way to do this using find?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86394/108618

Answer (score 0):

#### I only want to get the paths of the bottom level directories

Use the `-links 2` command line option.

> You can use `-links` if your filesystem is POSIX compliant (i.e. a
> directory has a link for each subdirectory in it, a link from its
> parent and a link to itself, thus a count of 2 links if it has no
> subdirectories).
>
> The following command should do what you want:
>
> ```
> find dir -type d -links 2
> ```
>
> However, it does not seems to work on Mac OS X (as @Piotr mentioned).
> Here is another version that is slower, but does work on Mac OS X. It
> is based on his version, with a correction to handle whitespace in
> directory names:
>
> ```
> find . -type d -exec sh -c '(ls -p "{}"|grep />/dev/null)||echo "{}"' \;
> ```

Source: [Use GNU find to show only the leaf directories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4269862/3536342) answer by [Sylvain Defresne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5353/sylvain-defresne)

Comment: The second command is [vulnerable to shell code injection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618).